# Nginx - wildcard static domain

Tags: php, caching, nginx, static

I'm trying to setup a wildcard static domain. My server hosts several domains, so i'd rather have one config for all of them, without having to manually add each and every one. so far i have this...

```
server {
    server_name static.* www.static.*;

    root /var/web/$host/;

    access_log off;
    error_log off;

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|ico|pdf|flv|swf|exe|html|htm|txt|css|js) {
            add_header        Cache-Control public;
            add_header        Cache-Control must-revalidate;
            expires           7d;
    }
    location  / {
            deny all;
    }
```

}

all files are stored in /var/web/example.com/ in that format, including subdomains /var/web/subdomain.example.com/

This domain is for static content (only images/css/js etc) and i want the root to be the same as the normal site, just it only allows the static files (hence why php fpm isnt in here)

There arent any nginx errors, but i get 404's, i have a feeling it's to do with root /var/web/$host/; Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googling around for a while lead me to this: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Where i found i could do regex in the server_name. So this worked for me:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^static\.(?<domain>.+)$;

    root /var/web/$domain/;

    access_log off;
    error_log off;

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|ico|pdf|flv|swf|exe|html|htm|txt|css|js) {
            add_header        Cache-Control public;
            add_header        Cache-Control must-revalidate;
            expires           7d;
    }
    location  / {
            deny all;
    }
```

}

Comment: This is the actual answer, but I can't yet accept it as the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try with

```
root /var/web/$http_host/;
```

and also I'd try with a fixed domain name (say www.static.whatever.com) to see if I can reach at least one static file. Then I'd go on adding more freedom degrees to the problem.

Also, I'd throw in

```
listen 80;
```

just to make sure.

Comment: I added the listen 80; and a fixed domain to test with, however no luck yet. I have tried $host,$http_host,$server_name and none of those work :S